# Iterate ansible Loops with multiple list and map them

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I can iterate the file (everything works fine using the below playbook), but I want to add a description to each VLAN using variables. So that every VLAN has a different description.
The variable file:

```yaml
all_vlans:
- name: DEvice1
  vlan_id:
    - 5
    - 21
    - 32 
  description: SW1
  for_serial: "OVA192FA3"
  for_host: "aoscx_1"
 
# I want something like below
- name: DEvice2
  vlan_id:
    - 11
    - 22
    - 32 
  vlan_desc:
    - VLAN_NO_11
    - VLAN_NO_22
    - VLANNO_32 
  description: SW2
  for_serial: "OVAA19FDF"
  for_host: "aoscx_2"
```

My playbook.

```yaml
  - name: Create VLAN as Per Variables
    aoscx_vlan:
      vlan_id: "{{ item.1 }}"
      name: UPLINK_VLAN
      description: '{{ item.0.description }}'
      # admin_state: up
      state: create   #create,update,delete
    when: my_var == '{{ item.0.for_serial }}'

    loop: "{{ all_vlans|subelements('vlan_id') }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.0.name }}"
```

Comment: => `description: "VLAN_NO_{{ item.1 }}"` If this is not what you are waiting for, please make clear what you actually get and what you exactly expect instead. See [mre]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want per-vlan descriptions, it seems simplest to restructure your data:

```
all_vlans:
- name: Device1
  vlans:
    - id: 11
      description: VLAN_NO_11
    - id: 22
      description: VLAN_NO_22
    - id: 32
      description: VLAN_NO_32
  description: SW2
  for_serial: "OVAA19FDF"
  for_host: "aoscx_2"
```

With that, you can write:

```
- name: Create VLAN as Per Variables
  aoscx_vlan:
    vlan_id: "{{ item.1.id }}"
    name: UPLINK_VLAN
    description: '{{ item.1.description }}'
    state: create
  when: my_var == item.0.for_serial
  loop: "{{ all_vlans|subelements('vlans') }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.0.name }}"
```

---

Note that I've corrected a syntax error in your `when` statement in the above example (you never nest `{{..}}` template markers inside a template, and a `when` statement is already an implicit Jinja template context).